# php says php made png is invalid

Tags: php, png

So I have a function that turns a jpeg into a png image resizes it then saves it.  Then a bit later i come back to it and use the image in a rotate function.  I keep getting errors though.  It says uploads/image.png isnt a valid PNG file.  The weird thing is that it only does then on php edited png files.  If i delete image.png and download a png from the internet name is image.png is works fine as long as i dont run it through the first resize script.

```
function load($filename) {
$image_info = getimagesize($filename);
$this->image_type = $image_info[2];
if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
    $imagecreated = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    $this->image = $imagecreated;
    $extention = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $basename = basename($filename, ".".$extention);
    $newname = "uploads/".$basename;
    imagepng($imagecreated, $newname.".png", 0);
// ....???

function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,
        $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Then i save the file with just a simple

```
imagepng(etc etc);
```

I go to the uploads folder and it looks fine.  its resized and everything.  I also noticed photoshop wont open the edited png either.

Also the line of code that produces the error is here..

`$image = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/image.png');`

Comment: You'll need to post some code to determine which libs you are using to process the png, it also just may be an error with that lib.  Consider checking issue trackers with the libs.

Comment: it sounds like your function isn't working :). show some code, and you'll probably have more to read.

Comment: can you open the PHP generated PNG in an image editor or viewer? If not, there's probably a bug in your PNG save code.

Comment: i can open it in windows photo viewer but not photoshop

Comment: So it looks like you are using GD Lib, can you post more of your save code, because that would be where the bug might be.

Comment: Check Whitespace output.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix is to add a NULL for your filters parameter (the last parameter in imagepng)

ie.

```
imagepng($image,$file_location,0,NULL);
```

I can't say this should be needed, but I read a similar case where someone noted they had to do this, may be dependant on the version of libpng or gd lib.

Comment: I gave it a try but with no success. I tried PNG_NO_FILTER too and its the same thing.

Comment: Ok--- Try, imagecreatefromjpg(), imagecreatetruecolor(), imagecopyresampled() and save the one from imagecreatetruecolor() not the one from imagecreatefromjpg()

Comment: Ok so i did a work around.  basically It works and the image rotates like it should but I ran into another problem.  When the image rotates the edges look horrible.  IF i rotate it about 45 degrees they look fine but for accurate rotation like 2 degree it looks so bad it's like there are several chunks out of the sides of the image.  anyone know what i can do about those?

Comment: That's because of the rotation. try it yourself with two pieces of paper, one on top of each other. When you rotate the top pieces, its corners will stick past the bottom sheet - and since you're dealing with fixed-width images, those protruding corners will get clipped.

Comment: oh no I know that.  I fixed that and put transparency on the edges.  I am talking like anti-aliasing type sides.